# ASP.NET MVC Show created files in custom scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

It is a really basic question, so I'm sure the answer is somewhere out there, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I've made a custom scaffold for a project I'm working in. I followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx). When used, it creates the controller and 3 other files, but I can't find how to automatically open all those new files. Is there a way?

Here it is how I'm creating the files:

```
public class CustomCodeGenerator : CodeGenerator
{
    // ...
    public override void GenerateCode()
    {
        // ...
        this.AddFileFromTemplate(Context.ActiveProject,
            string.Format("Controllers\\{0}Controller", controllerName),
            "ControllerTemplate",
            parameters,
            false);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of source control?

Comment: Not right now, but I will add it to a SVN later. Is it somehow related?

Comment: I'd say if you you (or something) add files to your Solution you would see them in your vcs. Maybe I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you, so I guess I didn't explain well. When the user creates a controller using my custom scaffolding, it creates the controller and three more classes. After doing this, in the Visual Studio, none of those files are shown. I want to show all of them.

Comment: Are they not added to the project?  Or is the solution explorer not refreshed?

Comment: Sorry again for the misunderstanding, the files are added to the project and shown in the solution explorer. I want them to be opened. Like if you wanted to edit them with the Visual Studio.

Comment: @Diego  Do you mean you want them to *automatically* open?  Because, if they are part of the project and show in Solution Explorer, you ought to be able to double-click on them and have them open.

Comment: Also:  are you putting the suffix `.cs` on the files?  (I'm assuming they are code files).  Because if they're suffix-less, Visual Studio won't know what they are or how to open them.

Comment: I am able to double-click on them and they do open. I want they to be automatically opened. The files have their extension. Three of them are `.cs` and one is `.cshtml`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that worked. After adding the files I did this for each added project item:

```
_DTE dte = (_DTE)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(_DTE));
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile(projectItem1.GetFullPath(), Constants.vsViewKindPrimary);
```